# Help with query_posts function

Tags: query-posts

I have a paid theme that has the following function manually hard-coded. It pulls the 8 latest posts and displays them:

```
global $do_not_duplicate;
global $post;

query_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page'        => '8',
    'post__not_in'          => $do_not_duplicate,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1
) );
```

I have looked at [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) and tried to modify the code to show posts from the news category only (category number 1):

```
global $do_not_duplicate;
global $post;

// Attempt 1
query_posts( array(
    'cat=1',
    'posts_per_page' => '8',
    'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
) );

// Attempt 2
query_posts( array(
    'category=1',
    'posts_per_page' => '8',
    'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
) );

// Attempt 3
query_posts( array(
    'category' => array(1),
    'posts_per_page' => '8',
    'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
) );

// Attempt 4
query_posts( array(
    'cat=news',
    'posts_per_page' => '8',
    'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
) );
```

Nothing worked. The same list of 8 recent posts from all categories was returned.

Comment: I ***strongly*** recommend against using `query_posts`, instead if you want to change the query, modify it with the `pre_get_posts` action, don't replace it, and if you absolutely must, use a standard `WP_Query` loop instead. There are no good situations to use `query_posts` and there are *always* better alternatives. If you find it in a premium theme this should be considered a red flag and a warning sign of poor code quality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `query_posts()` function is almost wholly unnecessary and is discouraged in favor of `WP_Query()`. That being said we can look at the [`WP_Query()` docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters) as they're almost the same.

The `cat` parameter accepts either a comma separated string or integer. In this case we can use:

```
query_posts( array(
    'cat' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => '8',
    'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
) );
```